# Why am I not able to access CSS properties with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not able to retrieve CSS properties on the `div`-element with the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log(
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderTopColor
  );
}
```

```css
div {
  border-top-width: 15px;
  border-top-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Return top border color</button>
```

Comment: because `element.style.whatever` returns the inline style on the element, not the computed style that is the result of style sheets... what you need to use `getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv")).borderTopColor`

Comment: Please define "_not working_".

Comment: I did define not working by saying the css properties on the div is not working, In other words, I don't see a border or width.

Comment: @thirstForKnowledge "_not working_" doesn't usually define anything, this case is not an exception. There's an alert which shows nothing ... we don't know whether you can see something or not unless you tell us. All the information we have is in your question. It's possible, that you saw a red border instead of the green, or maybe the border was 30 px wide, "_not working_" are just words you __never__ write to your question, if you want an exact answer. We know your code is "not working", why would you have asked in the first place, if the code would work ...

Comment: For the next time, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining comments and answers from others. For details you can refer those.

Two changes to be done to make it *working*

- Add Border Style: `border-top-style: solid;`
- Modify JS code to get the border color: `alert(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv")).borderTopColor);`

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <head>
   <style>
   div
   {
      border-top-width: 15px;
      border-top-color: green;
      border-top-style: solid;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
   <br>
   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Return top border color</button>
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
           alert(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("myDiv")).borderTopColor);
        }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the property values.Also borders are not visible unless style is specified.

The below snippet will return the color code in `RGB` format

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
  var elem1 = document.getElementById(elem);
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);
  var getBorderTop = style.getPropertyValue("border-top-color")
  console.log(getBorderTop);
}
```

```css
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 15px;
  border-top-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction('myDiv')">Return top border color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
     function myFunction() {  
   alert(window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementById("myDiv")).borderTopColor)
            }
```

play it [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzoMJL)

Answer (score -1):

You don't set a style to the border. By default it is none.
[Border-top-style](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-top_style.asp)

Or you can also use `border-top: 15px solid green;`

Also for getting styles which are not defined inline you have to use [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```css
div
   {
      border-top-width: 15px;
      border-top-color: green;
      border-top-style: solid;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
   <br>
   <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Return top border color</button>
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
          var elem = document.getElementById("myDiv");
          var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null);
          alert(style.borderTopColor);
        }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: @c-smile Edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDiv {
    border: thick solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change color of the top border</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderTopColor = "red");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is correct for changing the top border color.

Whenever we define the style prop in the style tag then we have permission to change it And define style prop correctly as given in the code.

I hope u understand the above code. If any query u can ask me

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.mystyle
{
  border-top: 15px solid green;      
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Return top border color</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
       document.getElementById("myDiv").className = "mystyle"; 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd be downgrading an answer that works.